# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) with nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, jquery-ui

**I am trying to get the html elements data at nodejs server. But I keep getting lot of errors in the browser. Here's is my html page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SimplyBPM | Customer 360 CRM | Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!-- SB css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sbCustom.css">

  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

    <!--  Header -->
    <div class="sbIncludeHTML" title="header.html">Include HTML here</div>

    <!--  Left Nav -->
    <div class="sbIncludeHTML" title="leftNav.html">Include HTML here</div>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">

        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>Customer 360 CRM <small>Dashboard</small></h1>

        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

          <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">  <!-- Box1 -->
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
                <div class="inner"><h3>9</h3><p>Unassigned</p></div>
                <div class="icon"><i class="ion ion-email-unread"></i></div>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="small-box-footer" onclick="filterList('ALL',0)">Show all <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./Box1 -->

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6"> <!-- Box2 -->
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-green">
                <div class="inner"><h3>3</h3><p>My Incidents</p></div>
                <div class="icon"><i class="ion ion-ios-list"></i></div>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="small-box-footer" onclick="filterList('MYRECORDS',0)">Show all <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./Box2-->

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6"> <!-- Box3 -->
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                <div class="inner"><h3>2</h3><p>New Incidents</p></div>
                <div class="icon"><i class="ion ion-ios-telephone"></i></div>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="small-box-footer" onclick="filterList('NEW',0)">Show all <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./Box3 -->

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6"> <!-- Box4 -->
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-red">
                <div class="inner"><h3>4</h3><p>Follow-up Today</p></div>
                <div class="icon"><i class="ion ion-ios-bell"></i></div>
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="small-box-footer" onclick="filterList('FOLLOWUPTODAY',0)">Show all <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
             </div>
            </div><!-- ./Box4 -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->

          <!-- Main row -->
          <div class="row">
            <!-- Left col -->
            <section class="col-lg-8 connectedSortable">

              <!-- Search Options -->
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><h3 class="box-title">Search</h3></div>
                <div class="box-body">

              <div class="form-inline">
              <!-- Search ID box -->
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="INCIDENT_ID">Incident Search ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control sbDataFields" id="INCIDENT_ID" placeholder="Search ID">
                </div>
              </div>

               <!-- Search Button -->
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <button type="button" name="search" id="search-btn1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="searchRecord();">Search</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <button type="button" onclick="window.location='incidentSearch.html'" name="search" id="search-btn2" class="btn btn-primary" >Advanced</button>
                 </div>
              </div>         
             </div>


              </div> <!-- ./Box Body -->
              </div> <!-- End of Search Box ./box-primary -->

            <!-- Table of Incidents -->
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <!-- box-header -->
                <div class="box-header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                <h3 class="box-title">Incident Table</h3>

                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- Table values -->
                <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover" id="incidentList">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Alert</th>
                        <th>Priority</th>
                        <th>Incident ID</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Created On</th>
                        <th>Assigned To</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm inline" id="pagination"> <!-- Scroll Buttons -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box-primary -->                        
           </section><!-- /.Left col -->

           <!-- right col (We are only adding the ID to make the widgets sortable)-->
            <section class="col-lg-4 connectedSortable">
              <!-- Chat box -->
                <div class="sbIncludeHTML" title="notes.html">Include HTML here</div>

            </section><!-- right col -->
          </div><!-- /.row (main row) -->
       </section><!-- /.content -->
       </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

       <input type="text" value="" id="CURRENT_FILTER_TYPE" style="display:none"/>

       <!-- Main Footer -->
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
          <b>Version</b> 2.3.0
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2015-2016 <a href="http://www.cgsits.com/simplybpm">CGS IT Solutions</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
      </footer>  <!-- ./Main Footer -->  

    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pleaseWaitDialogLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="pleaseWaitDialogLabel">Processing...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>

    <script src="files/common.js"></script>

    <script src="files/itsm.js"></script>

    <script src="files/sbIncludeHTML.js"></script>


<script>
        var totalRows = 0;
        var rowCount = 10;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            getAllRecords(0);
            getAllNotes();
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                    readOnlyNotes();
            });
        });

        function getAllRecords(rowOffset)
        {
            var dataString = "action=list&rowOffset=" + rowOffset  + "&rowCount=" + rowCount;
            $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/api/itsm/incident",
                data:dataString,
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
                    var returnMessage = checkResponse(response);
                    if(returnMessage == true)
                    {
                        generateTableHTML(response);
                        pagination(true,'LIST');
                    }
                    else if(returnMessage != false)
                    {
                        alert(returnMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function generateTableHTML(response)
        {
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
            var responseJSONList;
            if(responseJSON.TOTAL_ROWS && responseJSON.TOTAL_ROWS != null && responseJSON.TOTAL_ROWS != undefined)
            {
                totalRows = responseJSON.TOTAL_ROWS;
            }
            responseJSONList = responseJSON.RESULTS_SET;
            var incidentTable = document.getElementById("incidentList");
            var html = "";
            for(var i=0;i<responseJSONList.length;i++)
            {
                html += "<tr>";
                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    html += "<td class='glyphicon glyphicon-bell text-red'></td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    html += "<td></td>";
                }
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].PRIORITY; + "</td>";
                html += "<td><a href='incidentDetails.html?IID=" + responseJSONList[i].INCIDENT_ID + "'>" + responseJSONList[i].INCIDENT_ID + "</a></td>";
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].SHORT_DESC + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].INCIDENT_TYPE + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].STATUS + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].CREATED_DATE + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + responseJSONList[i].ASSIGNED_TO + "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            incidentTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = html;
        }

        function filterList(type,rowOffset)
        {
            $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
            var searchObject = new Object();
            var tempDate = new Date();
            if(type == "NEW")
            {
                searchObject["CREATED_DATE"] = yyyymmdd(tempDate);
            }
            else if(type == "FOLLOWUPTODAY")
            {
                searchObject["FOLLOW_UP_DATE"] = yyyymmdd(tempDate);
            }
            else if(type == "MYRECORDS")
            {
                searchObject["ASSIGNED_TO"] = "Troy";
            }
            else if(type == "ALL")
            {
                searchObject["1"] = "1";
            }
            var searchObjectString = JSON.stringify(searchObject);
            var dataString = "searchRequest=" + searchObjectString  + "&action=search&rowOffset="+ rowOffset +"&rowCount=" + rowCount;
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/api/itsm/incident",
                data:dataString,
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
                    var returnMessage = checkResponse(response);
                    if(returnMessage == true)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("CURRENT_FILTER_TYPE").value = type;
                        generateTableHTML(response);
                        pagination(true,'FILTER');
                    }
                    else if(returnMessage != false)
                    {
                        alert(returnMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function searchRecord()
        {
            $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
            var searchObject = new Object();
            $(".sbDataFields").each(function(){
                searchObject[$(this).attr("id")] = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
            });
            var searchObjectString = JSON.stringify(searchObject);
            var dataString = "searchRequest=" + searchObjectString  + "&action=search&rowOffset=0&rowCount=1";
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/api/itsm/incident",
                data:dataString,
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
                    var returnMessage = checkResponse(response);
                    if(returnMessage == true)
                    {
                        generateTableHTML(response);
                        pagination(false,'SEARCH');
                    }
                    else if(returnMessage != false)
                    {
                        alert(returnMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here's my nodejs server program.**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var $ = require('jquery');
var settings = {
        host: 'cgs-devdb.czspzuv6lcaw.us',
        database: 'Customer 360',
        user: 'cgsadmin',
        password: 'cypre55gs'
    };
// Express
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/dashboard.html', function (req, res) {
       res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "dashboard.html" );
    });

// Get information submitted
app.get('/api/itsm/incident', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log(req.body);
    var qb = require('node-querybuilder').QueryBuilder(settings, 'mysql', 'single');
    // Generating Query
    qb.select('*')
    .where(req.body)
    .get('SM_INCIDENT', function(err,response) {
        if (err) return console.error("Uh oh! Couldn't get results: " + err.msg);

        console.log("Query Ran: " + qb.last_query());

        console.log(response);
        res.send(response); // sending back the response to ajax
    });
});
// Start server
app.listen(8000);
console.log("API is running on port");
```

[These are the errors I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zrJ2.png)

[Here is the folder structure of my Node JS project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r2WF.gif)

**I am finding it difficult to get the exact html page because of the scripts are not being included. Help me out in finding the mistake.
Thanks !!**

Comment: I don't see your public folder in that list

Comment: make sure that all your static assets are inside the public folder

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to change:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

to:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Web-Content'));
```

Or just rename the `Web-Content` folder to `public`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I still get some errors.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' in html page. 

GET http://localhost:8001/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 
dashboard.html:16 

GET http://localhost:8001/assets/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css 
dashboard.html:22 
GET http://localhost:8001/assets/css/sbCustom.css 
dashboard.html:25 
GET http://localhost:8001/assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js 
dashboard.html:28 
GET http://localhost:8001/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
dashboard.html:31

 It still doesn't fetch the css, js, bootstrap and jquery scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It worked,  when I changed

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

To

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Comment: I thought your server js file was a level up in your directory structure. Unless you want everybody to be able to see your server side code, you're going to want to move it out of your public directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;// Heroku will need the PORT environment variable
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  console.log(next);
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is live on port ${port}!`));
// "start": "node server.js",










1. Add this server.js file in your root folder 
2. Add this in your package.json file
"scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run-script build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev-server": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=src/ node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "NODE_PATH=src/ node scripts/test.js",
    "prod": "npm run-script build && serve build"
  },
3. Install server package (npm install -g server)
and restart our server`enter code here`
```